# How to achieve function exp on BigDecimal in scala?

Tags: scala

I wanna to call exp on BigDecimal,while it seems that BigDecimal does not support this function directly.How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855775/bigdecimal-eulers-number-calculation-to-emulate-math-expdouble-a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
 def etox(x: BigDecimal, p: Int) = 
  Stream.from(1).takeWhile(_ <= p)
    .foldLeft((BigDecimal(1), BigDecimal(1)) -> BigDecimal(1)) {
      case (((fac, pow), res), n) => 
        val f = fac * n
        val p = pow * x
       ((f, p), res + p/f)
    }._2
```

It sums up the first `p` members of the Taylor series for e^x. Taylor series converges pretty quickly, so this should give you a fairly good precision even with relatively small `p` values. `etox(1, 20)` for example, gets 18 digits right (in about 100 microseconds), which is already better, than `Math.E` (`new BigDecimal(Math.E).pow(1)` takes ~70 micros).

You can control the precision vs. speed by adjusting the `p`.
On my laptop `etox(1938435340345L, 1000)` takes about 50 milliseconds, while `etox(1938435340345L, 10000)` took 17.5 seconds.

Note, that the higher values of `x` are, the greater `p` you need to get an adequate precision. For `x=1` for example, `p=20` is enough, as I mentioned earlier, but if `x=25`, then you need `p` to be at least `100` to beat the `.pow` precision.

I am wondering, why this is not linear. Must have to do with the work involved to calculate those huge factorials, and gc'ing memory it takes to represent them ...

As a compromise for higher `x` values, you can do something like:
`etox(1, 100).pow(25)`. This gives you better precision than `etox(25, 100)`, in about the same time. 
`BigDecimal(Math.E).pow(100)` takes 64 microseconds, and computes the first 14 digits accurately. `etox(1, 1000).pow(100)` takes 1.4 milliseconds, and is accurate to the 33rd digit.

**Update** actually, `etox(100, 1000)` gets 34 digits correctly in 1.1 millis ... so, I guess, it doesn't matter all that much which form to use. I would expect the difference to be more significant for larger `x` though.
For example `etox(1000, 1000)` is way off, while `etox(1, 1000).pow(1000)` is still pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

`math.exp(myDecimal.toDouble)`
with some loss of precision due to double encoding.