# Limitation of Math.exp Function in Java

Tags: java, double, precision, bigdecimal, exponent

I am implementation an algorithm in which I required high decimal precision so I am using BigDecimal but Math.exp only takes parameter in double.

Values are generated at run time and passed as parameter to Math.exp
i.e

```
BigDecimal mathEx = new BigDecimal( Math.exp(xMulXPoint5.doubleValue()));
Where xMulXPoint5 = -347222407183165.419208175
```

mathEx results value goes so small that the result shows a zero instead of the actual small value.

Can anyone please suggest any other way to solve this problem.

Comment: Even wolfram alpha doesn't want to compute this. What are you going to do with it, is it OK to just represent it by its log? For example if you're going to multiply this by something really big, then you could add the logs of both and hopefully get a more workable number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own exp function using BigDecimal, then using it, instead of Math.exp

I found this one. Maybe this thread will help

[BigDecimal Euler's number calculation to emulate Math.exp(double a)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855775/bigdecimal-eulers-number-calculation-to-emulate-math-expdouble-a)

Hope it helps

Comment: Would be better if you could add your own explanation and or example code than just post a link as links can become stale etc. so this answer can stand largely on its own. Posting links is fine as reference or additional reading.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't do it, because the result underflows the exponent: it would be approx -1.5E14, which can't be represented by a 32bit int (which BigDecimal uses for its scale)

Comment: thanks for advice, xlm

yes, i agree that we need to pay attention with how many precision we need to acquire. Thanks for reminding about that. harold